# 503/417 errors on Azure webapp deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed an Azure Webapp via a slot-swap deployment in ADO with an ARM Template. The App Service Plan is "Always-On".

Every once in a while the app fails to swap (thus the deployment fails). The message is below:

> ##[warning]Error: Failed to update deployment history. Service Temporarily Unavailable (CODE: 503)
>
> ##[error]Error: Failed to swap App Service 'name' slots - 'Slot' and 'production'. Error: ExpectationFailed - Cannot swap site slots for site 'name' because the 'Slot' slot did not respond to http ping. (CODE: 417)

This is the result after 30min of waiting. When it is successful, it only takes a few minutes. More frustrating is the fact that the web is not actually down, it's working fine and not throwing any exceptions or 5xx

Answer (score 1):

Turning off and turning back on the 'Auto-Swap' is one approach that you can try.
'Auto-Swap' can be turned on and off by going to `'App Service'` > `'Deployment Center'` >`'Slot'` > `'Configuration'.`
[image] Also, please refer the below links
[Troubleshoot swaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#troubleshoot-swaps) ,
[Troubleshooting steps to solve "502 bad gateway" and "503 service unavailable" errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503#troubleshooting-steps-to-solve-502-bad-gateway-and-503-service-unavailable-errors)

Comment: I don't see this in my setting.